# How to pass -ldflags to GAE build?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, go-build

I have an HTTP service written in Go. Inside `main.go` I have a global `version` string.

```golang
package main

var version string
```

Locally, I build using `-ldflags "-X main.version=$VERSION` where `$VERSION` is determined by the shell environment, like so:

```sh
VERSION=v0.16.0 go build ./cmd/app -ldflags "-X main.version=$VERSION
```

I've recently decided to trial Google App Engine and started with a basic YAML file:

```
runtime: go111

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

What can I set in the YAML file in order to instruct GAE to build with the equivalent ldflags to bake in my version string?

I should also mention I use go modules with `GO111MODULE=on` locally when building.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with you app.yaml file.
However, you can use [Cloud build](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories) to build and deploy your app to App Engine.
In your cloudbuild.yaml you can add a line to the build step

```
args: ['build', '-a', '-installsuffix', 'cgo', '-ldflags', '''-w''', '-o', 'main', './main.go']
```